# KIVY python: why is screen manager none type sometimes

Tags: python, kivy

Very often in my code, I need to say in a Screen object this:

```
self.manager.current = 'screenname'
```

But sometimes my interpreter says that the `None` type has no attribute `current`...

Is it normal that my screen manager disappears?

EDIT:

The problem happens when I add this piece of code to my project:

```
class EditClass(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EditClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.myinit()

    def go_to_home(self):
        self.manager.current = "home_screen"


    def myinit(self):

        self.box0 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.box1 = BoxLayout(spacing=-2, size=(50,50), size_hint=(1,None))
        self.box2 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding = (5,5,5,5), spacing = 5)

        self.btn_back = Button(size=(32, 50), on_press=self.go_to_home(), size_hint=(None, 1), text="<", background_color=(0.239, 0.815, 0.552, 1))
        self.btn_title = Button(text="Edit a class", background_color = (0.239, 0.815, 0.552, 1))
        self.btn_more= Button(size=(32, 50), size_hint=(None, 1), text="=", background_color = (0.239, 0.815, 0.552, 1))

        self.anchor0 = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='right', anchor_y = 'bottom', padding=(5,5,5,5))
        self.btn_plus = Button(text="+", size=(46, 46), size_hint=(None, None), background_color=(0.239, 0.815, 0.552, 1))

        self.box1.add_widget(self.btn_back)
        self.box1.add_widget(self.btn_title)
        self.box1.add_widget(self.btn_more)

        self.anchor0.add_widget(self.btn_plus)
        self.box2.add_widget(self.anchor0)

        self.box0.add_widget(self.box1)
        self.box0.add_widget(self.box2)
        self.add_widget(self.box0)
```

Comment: It doesn't disappear, it just not has been initialized when you did `self.manager.current = 'screenname' `

Comment: How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please post more code and we could help you.

Comment: I added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding `myinit` to `__init__` you could schedule it:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

...
class EditClass(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EditClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.myinit, 1)

    ...

    def myinit(self, *args):
        ...

...
```

Answer (score 1):

self.manager is None in a Screen object until that object has been added to a ScreenManager with the add_widget() method.

Answer (score 0):

As **John Anderson** mentioned earlier, the **ScreenManager** didn't add the **Screen** yet.

Working Example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
class test_app(App):
    def build(self):
        SM = ScreenManager()
        sc = Screen(name='your_screen_name')
        print(sc.manager) #None (*1)
        SM.add_widget(sc)
        print(sc.manager) #SM (*2)
        return SM
test_app().run()
```

**Note**, **(1)** You cannot access the `self.manager` attribute until you finish your `__init__` method. **(2)** You have access to your manager now.